# access file of the calling folder from Azure DevOps pipeline template

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

The azure pipeline templates is saved in separate repository. Currently multiple python projects with the same structure are calling a same template. In each project there is a enviroment.yml file in the root folder and will be picked to create a python environment. I would like to encapsulate this part in to the template(please see the code spinet below).

```
stages:

- stage: test
  displayName: Test
  dependsOn: []
  pool:
    vmImage: ${{parameters.vmImageName}}
  jobs:
    - job: test_environment 
      displayName: Test environment

      steps:
        - bash: |
            echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
            conda env create -f environment.yml --name $(Agent.Id)  //Issue!
            echo $(Agent.Id)
            export PYTHONPATH="src/"
            source activate $(Agent.Id)
          displayName: Create Conda Environment
```

For the line commented with **Issue!**, the pipeline seems looking for the `enviroment.yml` from the root folder where the templates is stored. How can I ask the template to picked the yml file from the calling folder's root without using parameter input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) (i.e. `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` or `Pipeline.Workspace`) to specify absolute path to environment.yaml:

```
conda env create -f $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/environment.yml --name $(Agent.Id)
```